# Crawling Unix for All .php Files in Specific Subdirectories

Tags: python, unix

I am trying to get all php files in any subdirectory on a unix server that follows these patterns:

```
./*/www/p3/
./*/www/P3/
./*/www/p3[some letters after a variation on p3 and P3]/
```

The .php files may also be in other subdirectories of these.

I have tried two different methods:

```
fls = glob.glob('./*/www/[a-z][3]/*')
fls.extend(glob.glob('./*/www/[a-z][3]/*/*'))
fls.extend(glob.glob('./*/www/[a-z][3]/*/*/*'))
```

which also happens to include another directory on these that I don't want 
("./*/www/h3" which each subdirectory has)

I have also tried this:

```
import os
import fnmatch
matches = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('./'):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.php'):
            matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
```

Which returns all files in a subdirectory that are php files.

Are either of these methods a good start? Should I be trying another way of matching the filenames?

Comment: Have you tried to combine both approaches: pick subdirectories with `glob.glob` and then walk them with `os.walk`?

Comment: @myaut I am not sure what that would look like. Glob returns a list of directory strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said, you may use `glob.glob` to pick top-level directories for `os.walk`

```
for top in glob.glob('./*/www/[pP]3*'):
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(top):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.php'):
                matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
```

Or you may use `fnmatch` to ensure that php file you found is at desired location:

```
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('./'):
    if not fnmatch.fnmatch(root, './*/www/[pP]3*'):
        continue    
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.php'):
            matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
```

First approach requires less filesystem operations than second.